# Mongodb dynamic multi tenancy with spring-data library

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

As of I know the spring-data library allows one MongoTemplate bean mapped to one Mongo database.

So if I need multiple database connections, I will have to define multiple MongoTemplate beans in config file.

In my application, new projects get added runtime so the respective Mongo databases. Hence it is not possible for me to maintain those connections in configuration file.

Is there any way to dynamically configure databases MongoTemplate.

I have gone through below solution suggested on most of the questions:

https://github.com/Loki-Afro/multi-tenant-spring-mongodb

But I am not quite convinced with this. Is there any way around ?

Comment: What problems are your facing while doing that ? Btw you just need to maintain the connection config in the configuration for different dbs and lazy load the mongo template for each of them when requested.

Comment: Okay. In the application some mongo databases are created at runtime. So I can not maintain configuration for those databases. I want to connect to these databases. How can I achieve that? The solution in the link  mentioned above would work, but it is kind of hacky.